# Adobe DTM Tool library not loaded

Tags: tags, adobe, adobe-analytics

we're facing a strange issue with Adobe Analytics library, set as a tool, which is not loaded at run-time by the DTM library itself, as usually does.
We tried different libraries, both custom code (H.26 or H.27 versions) and automatic App Measurement, but no one was loaded in the head of page.
The obvious consequence is the "s is not defined" JS error (s is the Tracker Object) in console.
We deployed several Analytics tool libraries via DTM and this never happened.
We explored the Net console in order to find possible "Not Found" script requests but we just found the successful main DTM library one.
Any help to find possible debug options or solutions are really appreciated.
Thanks a lot

Comment: My first guess: Go to the tool config, Library Management section. Is "Page code is already present" checked?

Comment: Right consideration but I had already checked it and it's not flagged..

Comment: `_satellite.getToolsByType('sc')` or `_satellite.getToolsByType('sc')[0].getS()` does that return anything?

Comment: Thanks @CrayonViolent, I've figured out to use the APIs but you pointed me the right methods. Here: http://192.168.1.2/VARIE/pending_tool_sc.jpg , you may check the different returns for this issued deploy and, under the orange break, a good one. The main differences are: 1) the issued "h" object contains pending array, the good one not 2) the issued "h" obj have no "initialized" and "initializing" properties 3) The "getS()" method is returning null for the issued case and the H.27 library prop for the second one. It seems like the issued deploy keep the library pending or something like that.

Comment: I can't actually see that image because 192.168.1.2 is localhost to you, not accessible to me :).  In any case, that does sound strange; I haven't seen that before. You said you tried auto vs. manual, several lib versions.. did you try just deleting the tool itself and trying it again? Might be some random hiccup with how DTM instantiated the tool.  Sounds like you probably need to open a ticket with ClientCare

Comment: Sorry @CrayonViolent, this is the public URL for the APIs returns: http://imageshack.com/a/img673/4495/besEQ3.jpg . With this you can check better I think. In any case, I will try to reinstall the Tool..damn! :)

Comment: 3 quick questions:
is the DTM script deployed in the <head>?
Any other scripts running that might cause a conflict with the s object?
is the " Enable EU compliance for Adobe Analytics " checked in the general config section? This will prevent the tool from firing.

Comment: No it's not enabled but does not matter because I found out the reason why. I had a conflict with a Data Element evaluating a querystring parameter. This Data Element is based on 's' plugin and when the DTM tries to parse it, the 's' obj is probably not defined yet. I'm deep into solving it. Thanks anyway as usual ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No it's not enabled but does not matter because I found out the reason
>   why. I had a conflict with a Data Element evaluating a querystring
>   parameter. This Data Element is based on 's' plugin and when the DTM
>   tries to parse it, the 's' obj is probably not defined yet. I'm deep
>   into solving it. Thanks anyway as usual ;)

That's right: when you define a data element in the interface, it gets evaluated before any of the tools, so `s` object does not exist yet.

If you are simply trying to set a data element to the value of a url parameter, there is an option in the **Type** dropdown for **URL Parameter** you can use.

If your data element is a **Custom Script** type, there are some built-in `_satellite` methods you can use:

```
_satellite.getQueryParam()
```

This one is case-sensitive so if you have `foo=bar` and you pass 'FOO' to it, it will not match.

```
_satellite.getQueryParamCaseInsensitive()
```

This one is case-insensitive so if you have `foo=bar` it will match on 'foo','FOO','Foo',etc..

Comment: Thank you @Crayon, I will treasure those methods in case of need. At this moment, I solved using a Page-load rule where the same Data Element is evaluated later and the 's' obj is defined.