# Adobe DTM Data Element _satellite.getQueryParam()

Tags: adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

I need to get query param value in Data Element custom JS, I found the following answers.

[Adobe DTM Tool library not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31185421/adobe-dtm-tool-library-not-loaded)

[Adobe DTM to set query string in eVar and sProp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496244/adobe-dtm-to-set-query-string-in-evar-and-sprop)

But the _satellite.getQueryParam() and _satellite.getQueryParamCaseInsensitive() are not safe to use (https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/object_reference.html), is there any alternative way in DTM to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the "unsafe" functions (especially a common one like _satellite.getQueryParam()) are probably ok to use (I've seen them used without any issue for 4 years or so)- just be aware that you may need to change them when/if you upgrade to Adobe Launch.

But if you want something not on the _satellite object, the Adobe Analytics library has a built in function you can use- s.Util.getQueryParam (https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/util_getqueryparam.html). Note, if you are letting DTM manage your library, you'll only be able to use that s.Util.getQueryParam in code blocks associated with Adobe Analytics (because of scope issues)- so it wouldn't work in the third party tag code block.